# I want to route a key to a different view?

Tags: sapui5

I'm reading the official documentation. However it only shows me how to route the model to a different view and I want to route a key? Experts any suggestions?

Comment: Does "route a key" mean you want to pass an entity key as part of the hash?

Comment: i want to be able to pass a key from one view to another.

Comment: thats what Routing is doing, passing keys to other views. I dont get the Point. I think what you are looking for is how to Transfer data from one view to another, or values or objects. but this not the concept of Routing and maybe should start working off that error ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass data between Views you could either use a Model with is accessible to both - for example one that has been created in the Component.

---

Or you could add a query parameter to your routing to enable the user to bookmark the state. For that, modify the route-pattern to look like this:

```js
{
    "pattern": "employees/{employeeId}/resume:?query:",
    "name": "employeeResume",
    "target": "employeeResume"
}
```

When you do a navigation you can then add any key-value pairs to your URL to transfer data between views. The following call will make the URL-hash look like this: `#/employees/3/resume?tab=Projects`

```js
oRouter.navTo("employeeResume", {
    employeeId : 3,
    query: {
        tab : "Projects"
    }
});
```

Examples taken from the [Developer Guide](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b8561ff6f4c34c85a91ed06d20814cd3.html). Also see the [API Reference for Route](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.Route.html).